# Example - Homogeneity

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators

If $a(x,\xi)$ is of $C^{\infty}$ class and positively homogeneous of degree m for $|\xi|\geq1$, i.e.,
$$
           a(x, t\xi) = t^{m} a(x, \xi), |\xi| \geq 1, t\geq1,
$$
then $a \in S^{m}_{1,0} = S^{m}$.

We need to prove that $|\partial^{\alpha}_{x}\, \partial^{\beta}_{\xi} a(x,\xi)| \leq C (1+|\xi|)^{m-|\alpha|}$, but I don't have a good idea for bounding the expression above by a polynomial.

I tried to derivate the expressions, but this doesn't help me. I tried to put the function $a$ on the left as a quotient to try to find some clue, but one more time this doesn't help.

Please, can you help me? I need this example done for my work.

Comment: Hint: let $r=|\xi|$ so that $\xi = r\xi/|\xi|$, and using homogeneity, prove that if $r\geq 1$, $|\partial^N_r a(x,r\xi/|\xi|)|\leq C_{N,m} r^{m-N}$. This should give you an idea of how to prove it in full generality.

Comment: In the case, how can I make the constante $C_{N,m}$ and the term $r^{-N}$ to appear? For me, the inequality is not so direct. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well, from homogeneity you know that $a(x,r\xi/|\xi|) = r^m a(x,\xi/|\xi|)$. This is just a monomial in $r$ (since $a(x,\xi/|\xi|)$ is independent of $r$), which you can differentiate easily: $\partial_r^N r^m = (m-1)...(m-N-1)r^{m-N}$. Then evaluate at $r=|\xi|$.

Comment: But even doing that how can I bound the derivates by a constant and what can we do with the derivates with respect to x?

Comment: What do you mean? $\partial_r^N a(x,r\xi/|\xi|) = a(x,\xi/|\xi|) \partial_r^N r^m$, and you can take as many $x$ derivatives as you want since $a$ is smooth.

Comment: Also, you won’t be able to get your stated bound with constant = 1, you need a constant in front which depends  on $m,N$, and the derivatives of $a$.

Comment: Oh, yeah! My question was about how we make the inequality appear. This is not clear for me. About the constant not being equal to 1 I understand.

Comment: II rolled this back because the OP changed the contents to a completely different question months later after getting a legitimate answer. This is not appropriate behavior for this site.

Answer (score 2):

By the chain rule,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}a(x,r\tfrac{\xi}{|\xi|}) = \sum_{i=1}^n(\partial_{\xi_i}a)(x,r\tfrac{\xi}{|\xi|})\frac{\xi_i}{|\xi|}$$

By repeated applications of the chain rule and evaluating at $r=|\xi|$, we get

$$ \frac{\partial^N}{\partial r^N}a(x,r\tfrac{\xi}{|\xi|})\big|_{r=|\xi|} = \sum_{i_1=1}^n\dots \sum_{i_N=1}^n(\partial_{\xi_{i_1}}\dots\partial_{\xi_{i_N}}a)(x,\xi)\frac{\xi_{i_1}}{|\xi|}\cdots\frac{\xi_{i_N}}{|\xi|} \tag{*}$$

But by homogeneity,

$$\frac{\partial^N}{\partial r^N}a(x,r\tfrac{\xi}{|\xi|}) = \frac{\partial^N (r^{m})}{\partial r^N}a(x,\tfrac{\xi}{|\xi|}) = (m-1)\dots(m-N+1)r^{m-N}a(x,\tfrac{\xi}{|\xi|})$$

Now, for any multi-indices $\alpha,\beta$ with $|\beta|=N$, we may bound $
\partial^\beta_\xi a(x,\xi)$ by the right hand side of (*), since the sum includes all possible combinations of $N$th order derivatives in $\xi$. Therefore, we get

$$|\partial^\alpha_x\partial^\beta_\xi a(x,\xi)| \leq (m-1)\dots(m-N+1)|a(x,\tfrac{\xi}{|\xi|})||\xi|^{m-N}$$

But $a$ is smooth, so in particular $|\partial^\alpha_x\partial^\beta_\xi a(x,\xi)|$ is bounded near $\xi=0$ and for $x$ in any arbitrary compact set $K$. Hence we may replace $|\xi|$ with $(1+|\xi|)$ above to obtain

$$\sup_{x\in K}|\partial^\alpha_x\partial^\beta_\xi a(x,\xi)| \leq A_{m,N,K}(1+|\xi|)^{m-N}$$

Where $A_{m,N,K}$ is a constant depending on $m,N,K$ and derivatives of $a$, so that $a\in S^m$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really help me!

Comment: In the proof, can we use $\xi = 0$? In the question, we are considering $|\xi| \geq 1.$ And what argument do use to eliminate the expression $|a(x, \xi/|\xi|)|$ at the end of the proof?

Comment: To your first question, it depends whether you want the desired bound to hold for all $\xi$ or only $|\xi|\geq 1$. My bound holds for all $\xi$. To your second question, $a$ is smooth, so it particular it is bounded by some constant $C_K$ on $(x,\xi)\in K\times S^1$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle.